# Change the appearance of cache files in Android

Tags: java, android, caching

For my app I download some resources like images and small mp3 and save them in the external storage (at /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.packagename/cache for example. 
But I don't want that if a user explores that folder finds all the resources in a "common format".

One of my options is to remove the extensions (I know it's easy to guess the file type even if it have not extension but is a basic protection against most users)

I have noticed most of the programs that have their caches at the external storage don't have their cache as raw files.

I wonder if is there any easy way (with some class or something) for "hiding" those files and access them transparently or I must implement my own system

(It is not vital that these files remain hidden but I'd like keep those resources "unknown" unless a user takes a special trouble to see them)

Thanks

Comment: are you using `cache` with `WebView` ?

Comment: No. Are basically images and mp3 for using it as resources in my app (like bitmaps in imageviews,videos, background sounds) but I can't add them to the project because they must change over the days frecuently (I ask the user before download any content)

Comment: but the `cache` could be cleared by the system unpredictable, so i think you need to save the files in specific location for your application on sd card, isn't it?

Comment: Yes I was using the cache but when I noticed that I considered to change to the sd. But if I use the internal storage all the downloaded temporal files appear as space used by my app and if I use the external storage the basic user have access to the files with only mounting the phone in usb mode. I want to use the second but with some precautions

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ObjectOutputStream`, it will save data as binary data, when the user tries to open it, even using Text Editor, it will show corrupted data, and here some sample how to use it [Writing objects to file with ObjectOutputStream](http://www.javadb.com/writing-objects-to-file-with-objectoutputstream)